# Get all library jars in separate folder

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

I have Maven Eclipse Java project. I would like to ask maven copy all required libraries to `aaa` folder durin `Eclipse->Run->Run as->Maveven build-> package` process. I have configured plugin for this purposes:

```
                 <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <id>copy-dependencies</id>
                            <phase>prepare-package</phase>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>copy-dependencies</goal>
                            </goals>
                            <configuration>
                                <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/aaa</outputDirectory>
                                <overWriteReleases>false</overWriteReleases>
                                <overWriteSnapshots>false</overWriteSnapshots>
                                <overWriteIfNewer>true</overWriteIfNewer>
                            </configuration>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                </plugin>
```

But looks like adding this plugin takes no action during package and no folder and files are create. How to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

The configuration looks fine. Make sure it is in the `<build><plugins>` area of the POM, not in the `<pluginManagement>`.